# Unable to modify some setting in MyEclipse

Tags: myeclipse

While working with some projects checked out from Git, we get errors with modifying the project settings in MyEclipse. I am trying to modify the deployment values in my workspace and it is not letting me (screenshot below).
[image]

Comment: Have you contacted the support of this commercial product?

Comment: Not yet. Planning to do if there is nothing I can do from my side.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lot of information to go on, here (e.g. what is the version of MyEclipse, what type of project is this, what properties page are you switching from, the OS and version, whether this has worked before, the error log - but please don't paste that in here - and so on).

However, here are some actions that might help resolve it:

- Firstly, try a fresh empty workspace then import the project from the old workspace, or better still import again from Git. This would help clean up possibly corrupted settings in the workspace.
- Another thing to try is to launch MyEclipse with the -clean option (just add that option to the top of your myeclipse.ini file, found in the installation folder).

@Howlger is right, though, this is a commercial product and we may be better able to help if you raised the issue in the [MyEclipse support forums](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topics/myeclipse/).